# passing value object to itemRenderer

Tags: flex3, itemrenderer

how can access/pass a value object in a custom itemrenderer? The item renderer represents a field in my datagrid and i want to be able access properties from my VO.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to override the set data method of the item renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            //Strongly typed VO for use in binding.
            [Bindable]
            private var myValueObject:MyValueObject;

            override public function set data(value:Object) : void
            {
                //we don't want to update if the value is the exact same.
                if(data === value)
                    return;

                //you could simply access the data property but I think
                //it is nicer to have strong typing for code hints
                super.data = myValueObject = value;
                validateNow();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:Label text="{myValueObject.name}"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: thanks but its not the actual contents of the dataprovider i want to update, its actually an object i create in another part of the application.

Comment: add the proper VO as a property of the data that is being rendered. Item renderers should render a single data object and perhaps dispatch events. When I want renderers to affect other data in an application I dispatch an appropriate event that triggers that sort of reaction.

you might update your question to be a little clearer in regards to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach?

Item renderer ItemRendererLink.mxml:

```
            public function goTo():void {
                Alert.show(goToScreen + " " + data.item_num);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:LinkButton>
```

parent component:

```
    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="item_num"
        headerText="Item #">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <e:ItemRendererLink goToScreen="item"/>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>
```